# Is there a topic that is published to when a robot gets stuck?

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS Kinetic on a Turtlebot Burger 3. It's using the basic turtlebot packages which can be found on ROBOTIS.

Basically, when my turtlebot gets stuck during navigation, I want it to perform some other task (not necessarily related to navigation). I can perform this task without a problem, but I want it to be triggered each time the robot finds itself as stuck. I figured the best way of doing that would be to see if there was anything regarding a robot "stuck" state that gets published somewhere.

Does such a topic exist within the basic Turtlebot3 Navigation package? Or, is there a way to access that information within ROS?

Thanks for your assistance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321010/is-there-a-topic-that-is-published-to-when-a-robot-gets-stuck?/) by [djcicala](https://answers.ros.org/users/40858/djcicala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2019-04-20**:
How about writing an [actionlib client](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) for move_base and wait for the state [ABORTED?](http://docs.ros.org/api/actionlib_msgs/html/msg/GoalStatus.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think the move_base node has a topic that is published by default when it is stuck, but it does execute recovery behaviors when it is stuck: http://wiki.ros.org/move_base . You could probably write a recovery behavior that either publishes to a topic, or just does the thing you're trying to do when your robot gets stuck.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short, no there is no topic that reports the robot "getting stuck" because there is no single definition for "getting stuck." You would have to write your own definition for that, depending on your demand.

---

Originally posted by [alextac98](https://answers.ros.org/users/32942/alextac98/) with karma: 113 on 2019-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1